# Search multiple values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I was able to search single value into multiple columns using following condition

```
select * from emp
where 'JOHN' in (firstname, lastname)
```

But, i want to check multiple values into multiple columns.
Eg. I want to search `'JOHN'`, `'SCOTT'`, `'MARK'`, `'Ann'` values from `firstname` & `lastname` column.

```
select * from emp
where 'JOHN' in (firstname, lastname)
```

Comment: Simply you can use `OR` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   emp
WHERE  firstname IN ('JOHN', 'SCOTT', 'MARK', 'Ann')
OR     lastname  IN ('JOHN', 'SCOTT', 'MARK', 'Ann')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do JOIN as subquery with all names

```
CREATE TABLE emp (firstname varchar2(100),lastname varchar2(100))
```

```
INSERT INTO emp VALUES ('JOHN', 'test')
```

```
select * from emp INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 'JOHN' name FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SCOTT' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MARK' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ann' FROM DUAL) t1 ON name = firstname OR name = lastname
```

| FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN | test | JOHN |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K25RKxpt)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option might be to specify all values you're searching for in a collection (built-in `sys.odcivarchar2list` would do; you don't have to create your own), extract them with `table` function (result is `column_value`) and join outcome to original table.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with emp (id, firstname, lastname) as
  2    (select 1, 'John', 'King'  from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Foot', 'Mike'  from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Ann' , 'Tiger' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Mark', 'Scott' from dual
  6    )
```

Query:

```
  7  select e.*
  8  from emp e join table(sys.odcivarchar2list('John', 'Ann', 'Mark')) t on
  9               t.column_value in (e.firstname, e.lastname);

        ID FIRSTNAME       LASTNAME
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1 John            King
         3 Ann             Tiger
         4 Mark            Scott

SQL>
```